# regex that matches and captures headings

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this Regex `/<h([2-4])>(.+)<\/h[2-4]>/g`
It matches all h2,h3,h4 and captures the level and heading-text.

Is it good enough or do you see room for improvement in terms of speed and robustness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use regex on [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). You can use `Element.querySelectorAll`. Replace `Element` with a reference to the DOM-element from which you like to select the headings.

```
var heading = document.querySelectorAll("h2, h3, h4");
```

[`QuerySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) (and his brother [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)) use CSS selectors to select elements from the DOM. You can supply multiple selectors using commas. This will select all `h2-4` elements. You can loop them with this code:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(heading , function(element){
    //do something with the element here.
    console.log(element.textContent); //EXAMPLE, display the text in the element.
});
```

Since `querySelectorAll` returns a node list (which is an arrayish object) we can pass it to `Array.map` (though not directly). We use `Array.prototype.map.call` to pass the node list to the map function as array. `Map` loops over every element in the node list.

Answer (score 1):

Make your regex to do a non-greedy match. And also make the regex to do back-referencing.

```
/<(h[2-4])>([^<>]+)<\/\1>/g
```

**OR**

```
/<(h[2-4])>((?:(?!<h\d+\b).)+?)<\/\1>/g
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rO3kJ1/8)

Comment: or `<(h[2-4])>(.+?)<\/\1>`

Comment: Is it possible to capture the number of the heading-lvl instead of h2,h3,h4 without having a 3d capture-group?

Comment: what do you mean by `heading-lvl` ? you mean this `/<(h\d+)>((?:(?!<h\d+\b).)+?)<\/\1>/g`